# Как перекрыть весь экран и разрешить кликать только в определенной области?

Tags: python, pygame

Хочу реализовать такую механику, при вызове функции:tavern_interface_func нужно чтобы весь прочий экран "блокировался" не воспринимал нажатия никуда кроме созданной области. Вот код для полноты картины (если есть предложения по оптимизации буду раз услышать)

```
import pygame
import math
import os
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

pygame.init()

FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

W = 1480
H = 820

ALWAYS = True

CENTER_SCREEN = (W // 2, H // 2)
TOP_LEFT = (W // W, H // H)
TOP_RIGHT = (W, 0)
TOP_MIDDLE = (W // 2, 0)
BOTTOM_LEFT = (W // W, H)
BOTTOM_RIGHT = (W, H)
MONEY_NAME_POS = (W - 50, H // H)
MONEY_NUM_POS = (W - 70, H - 550)
MONEY_POS = (W - 190, H // 2)
TAVERN_POS = (500, 630)

SHADOW = (0, 0, 0, 150)

INCREMENT_MONEY_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
CHANGE_IMAGE = pygame.USEREVENT + 2
INCREASE_PERIODICALLY_MONEY = pygame.USEREVENT + 3

pygame.time.set_timer(CHANGE_IMAGE, 90)

pygame.time.set_timer(INCREASE_PERIODICALLY_MONEY, 5000) 

ARIAL_FONT_PATH = pygame.font.match_font('arial')
ARIAL_64 = pygame.font.Font(ARIAL_FONT_PATH, 64)
ARIAL_32 = pygame.font.Font(ARIAL_FONT_PATH, 32)

MONEY_SURFACE = ARIAL_32.render('Money', True, (248, 184, 0))  
MONEY_RECT = MONEY_SURFACE.get_rect()
MONEY_RECT.midtop = MONEY_NAME_POS

COINFLIPP_PATH = "arts/coin_flip"
COINFLIPP_IMAGES = os.listdir(COINFLIPP_PATH)

buildable_house1 = 0

money = 500
firsthome_tick = 1
firsthome_tick_value = 1
prise_first_house = 10

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H), pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.set_caption("Town")

show_money_earning = False  
show_build_interface = False 
show_first_building = False 
show_tavern_building = False 
open_tavern_interface = False 
allow_clicks_outside_tavern = False

shadow_surface = pygame.Surface((W, H), pygame.SRCALPHA)  
shadow_surface.fill(SHADOW)
interface_surface = pygame.Surface((W, H), pygame.SRCALPHA)  
interface_surface_rect = interface_surface.get_rect(topleft=(W // 10, H // 10))
background_image = pygame.image.load('arts/BGCastle.jpg')  
money_image = pygame.image.load('arts/Coin.png')  
money_image = pygame.transform.scale(money_image, (100, 100))
money_rect = money_image.get_rect(topleft=MONEY_POS)
build_interface_icon = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/icons/Home_interface.png'), (80, 80))
build_interface_icon_rect = build_interface_icon.get_rect()
intarface_image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('Arts/interfaces/Intarface.png'), (300, 300))
intarface_image_rect = intarface_image.get_rect(bottomright=BOTTOM_RIGHT)
build_interface = pygame.image.load('Arts/interfaces/Build_interface.png')
build_interface_rect = build_interface.get_rect(midright=(W, (H // 2) - 10))
build_interface_icon_rect.midbottom = (intarface_image_rect.midbottom[0], intarface_image_rect.midbottom[1] - 20)
money_earning = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/Coin.png'), (90, 90))
money_earning_rect = money_earning.get_rect()
money_earning_bg = pygame.image.load('Arts/interfaces/Money_earn_BG.png')
money_earning_bg_rect = money_earning_bg.get_rect(midright=(W, (H // 2) - 10))
coinflipp = pygame.image.load('arts/coin_flip/1.1.png')
coinflipp_rect = coinflipp.get_rect()
first_home_interface_buying = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/icons/1sr_ Home_icon.png'), (55, 55))
first_home_interface_buying_rect = first_home_interface_buying.get_rect()
first_home_interface_buying_rect.midtop = (build_interface_rect.midtop[0] - 83, build_interface_rect.midtop[1] + 48)
first_home_building = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/structures/builds/1st_home.png'), (200, 113))
first_home_building_rect = first_home_building.get_rect()
tavern_icon = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/structures/battle_builds/tavern_struc.png'), (53, 53))
tavern_icon_rect = tavern_icon.get_rect()
tavern_icon_rect.midtop = (build_interface_rect.midtop[0] - 83, build_interface_rect.midtop[1] + 128)
tavern_main = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/structures/battle_builds/tavern_struc.png'), (120, 115))
tavern_main_rect = tavern_main.get_rect(topleft=TAVERN_POS)
tavern_interface = pygame.image.load('Arts/interfaces/tavern.png').convert_alpha()
tavern_interface_rect = tavern_interface.get_rect()
exit_button = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load('arts/interfaces/exit.png'), (50, 50))
exit_button_rect = exit_button.get_rect(center=TOP_RIGHT)
hero_jeen = pygame.image.load('arts/heroes/jeen.png')

coinflip_index = 0

def money_earning_func():
    if show_money_earning:
        screen.blit(money_earning_bg, money_earning_bg_rect)
        screen.blit(money_image, MONEY_POS)
        money_rect.topleft = MONEY_POS

def build_interface_func():
    if show_build_interface:
        screen.blit(build_interface, build_interface_rect)
        screen.blit(first_home_interface_buying, first_home_interface_buying_rect)
        screen.blit(tavern_icon, tavern_icon_rect)

def tavern_interface_func():
    if open_tavern_interface:
        interface_surface.blit(tavern_interface, (W // 10, H // 10))
        interface_surface.blit(exit_button, (TOP_RIGHT))
        screen.blit(shadow_surface, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(interface_surface, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(exit_button, (0, 0))

running = True
while running:
    FPS.tick(120)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (
                event.type == KEYDOWN and (
                event.key == K_ESCAPE or
                event.key == K_q)):
            running = False
        if event.type == CHANGE_IMAGE:
            coinflipp = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(COINFLIPP_PATH, COINFLIPP_IMAGES[coinflip_index])), (80, 128))
            coinflip_index += 1
            if coinflip_index >= len(COINFLIPP_IMAGES):
                coinflip_index = 0
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_LEFT:
                if money_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print("moneyern work")
                    money += 1
                if not show_build_interface:
                    if money_earning_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and money_earning_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        show_money_earning = True
                if not show_money_earning:
                    if build_interface_icon_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and build_interface_icon_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        show_build_interface = True
                if first_home_interface_buying_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and money >= prise_first_house:
                    show_first_building = True
                    if show_first_building:
                        money -= prise_first_house
                        prise_first_house += round(prise_first_house * 0.35)
                        print(prise_first_house)
                        if prise_first_house >= 15:
                            firsthome_tick += math.ceil(firsthome_tick / 5)
                if tavern_icon_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print("work")
                    show_tavern_building = True
                if tavern_main_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    open_tavern_interface = True
                if allow_clicks_outside_tavern and not tavern_interface_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    pass
            if event.button == pygame.BUTTON_RIGHT:
                if money_earning_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and show_money_earning:
                    show_money_earning = False
                elif build_interface_icon_rect.collidepoint(event.pos) and show_build_interface:
                    show_build_interface = False
        if event.type == INCREASE_PERIODICALLY_MONEY:
            if show_first_building:
                money += firsthome_tick
                print("Money", str(firsthome_tick))
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
    money_earning_rect.topleft = (W - 100, H - 100)
    screen.blit(intarface_image, intarface_image_rect)
    screen.blit(money_earning, (W - 100, H - 100))
    screen.blit(build_interface_icon, build_interface_icon_rect)
    screen.blit(coinflipp, (W - 170, -10))

    money_counter_surface = ARIAL_64.render(str(money), True, (248, 184, 0))
    money_counter_rect = money_counter_surface.get_rect()
    money_counter_rect.midtop = (MONEY_NAME_POS[0], MONEY_NAME_POS[1] + MONEY_SURFACE.get_height())
    screen.blit(MONEY_SURFACE, MONEY_RECT)
    screen.blit(money_counter_surface, money_counter_rect)


    if show_tavern_building:
        screen.blit(tavern_main, (500, 630))
    if show_first_building:
        screen.blit(first_home_building, (200, 620))
    if show_money_earning:
        money_earning_func()
    if show_build_interface:
        build_interface_func()
    if open_tavern_interface:
        allow_clicks_outside_tavern = True
        tavern_interface_func()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить безумный костыль, но он точно сработает: мы ставим на мышку "Low Level Hook". Определяем диапазон координат где кликать можно, а где нельзя, просто блокируем ввод мышки.

Я нечто подобное реализовывал:

```
if self.if_block(event):   
            return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(self.mouse_hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        else:
            return -1
```

Т.е. можно перехватить нажатие и уничтожить его. При этом ни одна программа дальше установленного хука его не обработает(как пример, на крестик уже не нажать).

[image: Блокируем ЛКМ]

Так что можно написать свой хук или посмотреть в сторону самого pygame:

```
pygame.event.set_grab(True)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)
pygame.event.set_grab(False)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)